# How Best to Unpack a Pandas Dataframe of Tuples?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, tuples

Probably really straightforward but I'm having no luck with Google. I have a 2 column dataframe of tuples, and I'm looking to unpack each tuple then pair up the contents from the same position in each column. For example:

```
Col1     Col2
(a,b,c)  (d,e,f)
```

my desired output is

```
a d
b e
c f
```

I have a solution using loops but I would like to know a better way to do it - firstly because I am trying to eradicate loops from my life and secondly because it's potentially not as flexible as I may need it to be.

```
l1=[('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f','g'),('h','i')]
l2=[('j','k'),('l','m'),('n','o','p'),('q','r')]

df  = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l1,l2)),columns=['Col1','Col2'])

df
Out[547]: 
        Col1       Col2
0     (a, b)     (j, k)
1     (c, d)     (l, m)
2  (e, f, g)  (n, o, p)
3     (h, i)     (q, r)

for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in range(len(df.iloc[i][1])):
            print(df.iloc[i][0][j], df.iloc[i][1][j])
    
a j
b k
c l
d m
e n
f o
g p
h q
i r
```

All pythonic suggestions and guidance hugely appreciated. Many thanks.

Addition: an example including a row with differing length tuples, per Ch3steR's request below - my loop would not work in this instance ('d2' would not be included, where I would want it to be outputted paired with a null).

```
l1=[('a','b'),('c','d','d2'),('e','f','g'),('h','i')]
l2=[('j','k'),('l','m'),('n','o','p'),('q','r')]

df  = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(l1,l2)),columns=['Col1','Col2'])
```

Comment: [`df.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) passing both columns. You will need a newer version of pandas to do this.

Comment: ALollz - in the majority of cases, yes, but, in a handful of cases Col1 will have a longer tuple than Col2. This is one of the reasons that I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: @piemashandgravy Can you edit the current example to incorporate the case where tuple lengths are not the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send each Series `tolist` and then reconstruct the DataFrame and `stack`. Then `concat` back together. This will leave you with a `MultiIndex` with the first level being the original DataFrame index and the second level being the position in the tuple.

This will work for older versions of pandas `pd.__version__ < '1.3.0'` and for instances where the tuples have an unequal number of elements (where `explode` will fail)

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[col].tolist()).stack().rename(col) 
                 for col in df.columns], axis=1)

    Col1 Col2
0 0    a    j
  1    b    k
1 0    c    l
  1    d    m
2 0    e    n
  1    f    o
  2    g    p
3 0    h    q
  1    i    r
```

Comment: This nails it @ALollz, many thanks. I also tried it with the scenario where a row has a longer tuple in one column than in the other, and I got the outcome I wanted. Fascinating to see how it works too.

Answer (score 3):

if the tuples length are always matching and you don't have the newer version of pandas to pass a list columns to `explode`, do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.concat([df.Col1.explode(), df.Col2.explode()], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

  Col1 Col2
0    a    j
1    b    k
2    c    l
3    d    m
4    e    n
5    f    o
6    g    p
7    h    q
8    i    r
```